# Spring: Using @Retryable and @RefreshScope to retry JMS Topic URL from config repo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, refresh, spring-retry

I am trying to implement the annotations `@RefreshScope` and `@Retryable` in my code. I want them to work simultaneously but I am not sure if it is possible. Currently, `@Retryable` works as it is suppose to. If the method throws an exception, it will retry max:5 times with 6 second down-times. The problem: I need `@Value` property to be refreshed, and `@RefreshScope` should take care of this BUT a different method takes `@Value` property as an argument. So really, if `methodB` that has `@Retryable` fails, I need `methodA` that takes the `@Value` property to refresh. If not, `methodB` retries with the same incorrect values. You're probably confused so here is an example:

```
@RefreshScope
@Service
public class JMSTopicClient {

  @Value("#{'${jms.newTopic.topic}'}")
  private String newTopicDestination;

  private static int COUNTER = 0;


  public boolean methodA(String message, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> jmsHeaderDetails){
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(newTopicEnv);
    ConnectionInfo conInfo = connectionInfo.get();
    conInfo.topic = (javax.jms.Topic) ctx.lookup(destinationTopic);
    //rest of the code is irrelevant.
  }
```

Notice, `ctx.lookup(destinationTopic)` takes the value of `destinationTopic`. Ultimately, this is the method that needs to be refreshed in case the value is changed in config repo (if `methodB` fails/retries)

```
   @Retryable(value = { Exception.class }, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 6000))
  public boolean methodB(Document doc, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> jmsHeadersDetails) {
    COUNTER++;
    String xmlEventNotify = DocumentHelperFactory.get().convertDocumentToString(doc);
    boolean result = methodA(xmlEventNotify, jmsHeadersDetails);
    if(result == false) {
        if(COUNTER<5) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } else {
            COUNTER = 0;
            return result;
        }
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here, `methodB` is retrying, but it is retrying with the same incorrect values that `methodA` takes in. I need the whole process methodA-methodB to retry if methodB throws exception.
I'm confident there is a workaround but I cannot find any documentation where `@RefreshScope` and `@Retryable` work simultaneously.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works for me. It might be sensitive to the order that the interceptors are added to the proxy (dunno TBH). If you have a minimal sample - no JMS etc. - I could try and debug it for you.

Comment: @DaveSyer Thanks for the reply!